# Do we have a problem with sexist, and generally overly zealous moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation, policy, sexism

I’m sick of what I have noticed as overly zealous moderation when it comes to opposing, however gently, mildly, and courteously, the remake of apparently female users. The moderators appear especially concerned with shielding female users from having to face any disagreement from others to the extent of framing such disagreement as “abusive.”

It’s a long running pattern but I’ve just encountered an especially egregious incident of it and I am sick of it, while also wondering if anyone else had a noticed this phenomenon.

Comment: Heck, how do you even know who is male/female/etc. here?

Answer (score 5):

### Who's a female user here?

I most certainly do not claim to be female or male or anything - and I would prefer if people don't try to attribute that to me. As such I try to strive for neutral pronouns. **I am a user, my gender does not matter, and I believe nobody's gender in this community matters.**

As such, I do not believe we have a problem with sexist moderators.

#### about my name

For anyone claiming I use a "traditionally female" name, no, you are WRONG. A name on the internet does **not** indicate a gender. It could be a shorthand, my surnames, or just a nickname, and that all would be without gender identifier. So, yes, calling me any gender, despite **repeatedly stated wishes not to be gendered** is not ok - and by the way, harassment.

### "face disagreement from others..."

You can voice your disagreement by **voting** or by leaving a comment. [Comments however are ephemeral and should not be seen as keeping any information.](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

> When should I comment?
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

You do something different about comments than most other users, and that is problematic: you try to start a discussion. That is **not** what the comments are for. You also have in the past commented on several of my answers in a way that attacked me personally. At other times you were extremely pushy if you did not like how I interpreted something, often when your question did not have details in it. Note that the flagging reasons on a comment are somewhat grainy:

> - It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.
> - It's unfriendly or unkind.
> - It's no longer needed
> - Something else.

[image]

Pushing someone for an edit or comment is harassment. Showing disdain or prejudice against an answer or the answerer is bigotry. Using your commenting privilege to annoy someone is an abuse of the privilege just as well as harassment. Blasting half a dozen comments on one answer easily becomes annoying and abusive.

Attacking someone **personally** is unfriendly or unkind.

Comments that won't be acted upon can be flagged as "no longer needed" and many such comments get deleted.